Initialising Publisher object for Spring Events
I am a beginner when it comes to Spring and Springboot. I am currently learning Spring Events and while publishing an event I am repeatedly getting the null pointer exception for ApplicationEventPublisher object when calling the publishEvent() method.
The following is my Event Class:
public class EventClass extends ApplicationEvent {

    private String message;

    public EventClass(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

The following is my Publish Event Class:
@Service
public class PublishEvents {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void publishEvent(String message){
        System.out.println("Publishing events...");
        EventClass event = new EventClass(this,message);
        applicationContext.publishEvent(event);
    }
}

The following is the Listener class:
@Component
public class ListenerClass implements ApplicationListener<EventClass> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EventClass event) {
        System.out.println("Listener received messages..." + event.getMessage());
    }
}

Following is my main method and calling function
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringeventsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringeventsApplication.class, args);
        springEvents();
    }

    public static void springEvents(){
        PublishEvents publishMessage = new PublishEvents();
        publishMessage.publishEvent("Hi I think this works...");
    }

}

The above throws null pointer exception for application context object. I understand it needs to initialised but not how.
I have tried implementing it using ApplicationEventAware, and also tried to initialised the context , however in that case PublisherEvent bean not found error is thrown.

The NullPointerException occurs because the applicationContext is not being injected when you manually create an instance of PublishEvents using new PublishEvents() in your springEvents() method.
Dependency injection only works when the bean is managed by the Spring container.
so your main class should be :

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringeventsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private PublishEvents publishEvents;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringeventsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        springEvents();
    }

    public void springEvents() {
        publishEvents.publishEvent("Hi I think this works...");
    }

